# Response Server duration in Laravel Middleware

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-middleware

I am Trying to get the response Server Duration in my Middelware and save it in Sql DataBase , Here is my middelware

```
public function handle(LaravelRequest $request, Closure $next)
    {
       
        $this->startTime = microtime(true);

       return $next($request); 
    }
```

```
class AfterMiddleware  {
     
    public function handle(LaravelRequest $request, Closure $next)
    {
        
        $response = $next($request);
        
        $request->fingerprint();
        $RequestSaving = new Request();
        $endpoint=Endpoint::where("url",$request->url())->firstOrCreate(["url"=>$request->url()]);
        $RequestSaving->endpoint()->associate($endpoint);
        $RequestSaving->method = $request->getMethod();
        $RequestSaving->status = $response->Status();
        $RequestSaving->user_id = Auth::id();
        $RequestSaving->duration=microtime(true)-$this->startTime;
        $RequestSaving->result =$response->Content();
        $RequestSaving->save();   

        return $response;
    }

}
```

Everything works Fine only the part if the duration response that looks a littel bit complicated to me , Any ideas ?

Comment: btw, Laravel defines a constant `LARAVEL_START` which is the first statement that runs which is set to `microtime(true)` ... also i might do this database insert after the response has been returned (terminable middleware)

Comment: If these are two different middleware you can't use `$this->startTime` in the second one because it is defined in the first one